# How to change class of separate div when hovering over link using JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to change the class of the #hse div when hovering over a link, and revert back to the default class on mouseout. The link has been assigned the id "#hselink".  I placed the script below into the WP header, but it is not working. (The site is not available to view.)

I have tried searching here, using scripts provided, and the div does not change.

```
<a href="#" id="hselink">Health, Safety &amp; The Environment</a>
```

```
<script>
$("#hselink").mouseover(function(){
  $("#hse").addClass("boxshadow").removeClass("noshadow")
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your process by having the no shadow style be the default style of the div then simply toggling the class of `boxshadow`.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on("mouseover", "#hselink", function(){
        jQuery("#hse").toggleClass("boxshadow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That generated  - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: @adriancollins I apologize, I had a typo, I was missing the start `{` after `function()`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: So, now it shows this - (index):91 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Did you include jquery into your website?

Comment: Yes, it is loading JQuery

Comment: Correct - there is another script in the section to add scripts that has:
```
<script>jQuery('a.tp-caption[href*="#"]').addClass('smooth-scroll');</script>
```
and it is working. I put the new script below that and it generates the errors...

Comment: Ok, so the problem is your jquery is being called as `jQuery` and not `$`. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Is there way to add a toggle when they mouseout to go back to the original class?

Comment: You can add the style from the class to the link and the style from the class boxshadow simply overwrites in on mouseover. Using this method is clean requires less code but still accomplishes your goal. However, if you really want to go the route of having additional unneeded CSS and jquery, @taplar's suggestion does what you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a `mouseenter` event and a `mouseleave` event that flip each other back and forth.

```js
$('#hselink')
  .on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#hse').addClass('boxshadow').removeClass('noshadow');
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('#hse').removeClass('boxshadow').addClass('noshadow');
  });
```

```css
.noshadow { color: blue; }
.boxshadow { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="hselink">Health, Safety &amp; The Environment</a>
<div id="hse" class="noshadow">Toggle Me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but on these scripts I keep getting: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: That would mean you are not including jQuery in your page, or it is running in `noConflict` mode which means you would need to use `jQuery` in place of `$`. @adriancollins

Comment: Thank you, that was it, it appeared to be loading after.